# How to call a .bat file and set local environment variables in a single line on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I am calling a .bat file on windows. The .bat file relies on the presence of some environment variables.

How can I set these environment variables at the same time as calling the .bat file such that the environment variables are local to the .bat file and do not propagate as global variables.

I would ideally like to do this in one line...

Comment: If they are really file-specific, why not specify them in the file? - The other way is to pass parameters to the script.

Comment: This file is already written and comes part of another piece of software. I want to be able to call the bat file multiple times, each with different values for the variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `SETLOCAL`/`ENDLOCAL`. Variables assigned between those statements do not affect the rest of the script.

```
setlocal
set LOCALVAR=XYZ
call MyScript.bat
endlocal
```

You can write the four statements in a line if you prefer using `&` as a separator:

```
setlocal & set LOCALVAR=XYZ & call MyScript.bat & endlocal
```

Comment: It is important to note that SETLOCAL only works from within a batch file. So the code in this answer must be within a batch file - it will not work if used directly on interactive command line.